# Pasar variable a Querie laravel

Tags: laravel, update

Buenas noches estoy tratando de pasar la variable $id y no me la toma en el update.

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
     {
      
             // dd($id);  aca me imprime "id=3236" y si harcodeo el numero en el update funciona ok.

        $turnos=DB::update('update turnos set llegada=DATE_FORMAT(NOW( ), "%H:%i" ) 
                            where id = ?',[$id]);
```

Agradezco que me den una mano.
Gracias.-

Seguramente estoy haciendolo mal, reemplazando el update por eloquent tampoco me toma el $id. Tengo en mi vista index un boton

```
 <form action="/turnosdeldia/id={{$turno->id}}" method="POST">
    @csrf    
    @method('PUT')
          
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-success btn-sm">Presente</button>
     </form>
```

y en mi controlador la funcion

```
  public function update(Request $request, $id)
     {
       
             
       $resul =  DB::table('turnos')->where('id', $id)->update(['llegada' => Carbon::now()]);

        return redirect('/turnosdeldia')->with('status', '1');
    }
```

Si le harcodeo el id me funciona ok el update. y si imprimo el id con dd($id); me muestra "id=3238".

Gracias por el continuo apoyo.

Comment: No me hace update.
Quiero guardar la hora del momento actual
Pero si le harcodeo el ID si que me updatea.

Comment: Route::resource('turnosdeldia','App\Http\Controllers\turnodeldiaController');

Comment: voy a probarlo y les cuento, mil gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que no tienes muy claro cómo funciona Laravel. Si lo que quieres es hacer un update, Laravel por defecto actualiza esto a través de sus modelos. Por ejemplo, en su [documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#timestamps), te dice que si necesitas modificar esos campos, dentro de cada modelo, debes hacer:

```
const CREATED_AT = 'creation_date';
const UPDATED_AT = 'updated_date';
```

Y especificar el formato con que quieres que estos se guarden así:

```
protected $dateFormat = 'U';
```

Por lo general, el formato con el que se crea tus tablas para llevar el registro de la fecha de creación y actualización es timestaps.

Sino tienes modelos, los puedes hacer a través de las [query builder](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries) que son las que, por lo general, se usan cuando no tienes modelos. Por lo tanto deberías hacer algo como:

```
DB::table('turnos')->where('id', $var)
->update([
   'llegada' => now()
]);
```

Las consultas raw te pueden ocasionar problemas a la larga. En general te recomendaría leer atentamente la documentación de Laravel. Es bastante buena y fácil de leer.

Por otra parte, no te lo toma, porque estás pasando un array y esas se usan en otro tipo de consultas.

Comment: Ok, tienes razón en lo primero. Y el problema es que si vas a usar una herramienta, trata de usarla correctamente, al menos usando a disposición las cosas que te ofrece, sino vas a malgastar tiempo y esfuerzo tratando de usar algo que al final no necesitabas. Ese es el punto

Comment: Edite mi pregunta con mas detalle, y cambiando el modo de actualizarlo. Sin embargo no me toma el $id  creo que el problema debe de ser otro.

Comment: Bueno, si vamos al relativismo, igual le dije que a la larga eso le traería problemas y que no tenía claro cómo funcionaba la herramienta que usa. Pero cada quien programa como mejor le parezca.

Comment: Seguro no lo tengo claro., empecé a utilizarla hace 20 dias, estoy aprendiendo, y les agradezco la ayuda.

Comment: Creo que estás construyendo mal la ruta en tu action del formulario. En php solamente es válido hacerlo de esa manera, pero en laravel debes agregar ```{{ route('name.route') }}``` o ```{{ url('path/url') }}``` y así podría comunicarse con tu controlador y ejecutar tu código

Comment: Tranquilo, @JuanManuelFerrero, acá estamos para ayudarnos

Comment: Por cierto, si le vas a pasar una variable a la ruta, puedes hacer ```route('route.name', ['id' => 1])``` o ```url('user/profile', [1])``` esos son helpers que te ayudarán a manejar los actions de mejor manera dentro de tus formularios y así comunicarte con tu controlador de manera más eficiente.

Comment: Funcionó gracias